# AMP product page not being displayed on 'swipe to visit' for some websites while being displayed for others?

Tags: seo, images, amp

We have an AMP version of our product pages but that is not being displayed on 'swipe to visit' feature launched by AMP (Check details [here](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/internet/news/google-images-search-amp-pages-swipe-to-visit-mobile-web-2075667))

[image: image to swipe AMP demo]

If you click on the 2nd link below (bikewale.com)- you will see no option for "swipe to visit" but if you visit the page linked to this page - you will see "amphtml" tag (this page has amp version)

While if you click on 4th link (bikedekho.com) - you will see an option for "swipe to visit". Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

I did the same search and found similar results. The thing I noticed was that the AMP sign(the bolt sign) was missing from the Visit button of your product result. This means that the website has not been Optimized for AMP(Refer screenshots attached)[image: Image 1].[image: Image 2]

The AMP design should be in accordance with the AMP HTML specifications.

If you happen to have both AMP and non AMP version of a web page, use `“<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp-version.html" />”` for non AMP page to let Google know about the AMP versions. Also, use `“<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/regular-html-version.html" />”` to reference to the non-canonical page version.

Make sure to [validate AMP pages](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/validation-workflow/validate_amp/?referrer=ampproject.org).

Comment: We have done that. You can visit bikewale link from question - https://www.bikewale.com/m/royalenfield-bikes/bullet/ - the amphtml for it is https://www.bikewale.com/m/royalenfield-bikes/bullet/amp/ - and this is a valid amp page. Please check what can we do for this

Comment: I'm not able to find “<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp-version.html" />” in your source file.

Comment: view-source:https://www.bikewale.com/m/royalenfield-bikes/bullet/

Please search <link rel="amphtml"  in this links source code

Comment: Dumb suggestion but I see no `/` at the end of the tag in [the documentation.](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/discovery/?format=websites)